# VB Script that will manipulate a file name

Tags: vbscript, filenames

Ok, like many other people, I am a noob on VB Scripting.  What I am trying to do is create a VB Script that will manipulate a file name from Fulton A1032-CCC Adamsville to just A1032-CCC.  I have browsed many site trying to find the answer but only came up with on that halfway worked.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='H:\Darrell 2014 folder\Distview Wiki Revamp\To'} Where " _
    & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")

For Each objFile In colFiles
    strPath = objFile.Drive & objFile.Path
    strExtension = objFile.Extension
    strFileName = objFile.FileName

    If Left(strFileName, 7) = "Fulton " Then
        intLength = Len(strFileName)
        strFileName = Right(strFileName, intLength - 7)
    End If

    If Right(strFileName, 10) = " Adamsville" Then
        intLength = Len(strFileName)
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, intLength - 10)
    End If

    strNewName = strPath & strFileName & "." & strExtension
    errResult = objFile.Rename(strNewName)
Next
```

Please Help

Comment: VBScript != VB.Net != VB6. IOW, they're not synonyms - they're three separate languages. Please use **only** the relevant tags (in this case, `vbscript`). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the replace function instead?  For example:

```
Dim fileName As String

fileName = "Fulton A1032-CCC Adamsville"

fileName = Replace(fileName, "Fulton ", "")
fileName = Replace(fileName, " Adamsville", "")

MsgBox fileName
```

The output is A1032-CCC.  This also works if either or both of the search strings don't exist.

Answer (score -2):

Learn to count:

```
>> WScript.Echo Len(" Adamsville")
>>
11
>>
```

or write a function:

```
>> Function endsWith(b, t)
>>   endsWith = Right(b, len(t)) = t
>> End Function
>> WScript.Echo CStr(endsWith("Fulton A1032-CCC Adamsville", " Adamsville"))
>>
True
```

**Update wrt downvotes:**

As the downvotes indicate that there are at least two people who can't count either:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim strFileName : strFileName = "Fulton A1032-CCC Adamsville"
Dim intLength
WScript.Echo 0, qq(strFileName)

' assume the structure of the input data is:
' <todelete+blank><tokeep><blank+todelete>
WScript.Echo 1, qq(Split(strFileName)(1))

' the ot's code 'works' if you count correctly
If Left(strFileName, 7) = "Fulton " Then
    intLength = Len(strFileName)
    strFileName = Right(strFileName, intLength - 7)
End If
If Right(strFileName, 11) = " Adamsville" Then
    intLength = Len(strFileName)
    strFileName = Left(strFileName, intLength - 11)
End If
WScript.Echo 2, qq(strFileName)
```

output:

```
cscript 25689666.vbs
0 "Fulton A1032-CCC Adamsville"
1 "A1032-CCC"
2 "A1032-CCC"
```

Comment: How would you do it for various numbers of characters in the front and back of the file name.  The middle would be the same number of characters.